# socket.io server - pause listening and resume

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need a mechanism to start and stop socket.io server. When stop command is come, all clients disconnecting and server stop append new connection. When start function call, socket server append new clients connection in normal mode.

I'm trying this code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(function() {}),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(25544);

io.set('log level', 1);
io.set('close timeout', 240);
io.set('heartbeat timeout', 240);
io.set('heartbeat interval', 120);

io.startServer = function() {
    app.listen(25544);
};

io.stopServer = function() {
    app.close()
};
```

But when i'm calling app.close(), i'm taking error:

```
net.js:1236
    throw new Error('Not running');
          ^
Error: Not running
    at Server.close (net.js:1236:11)
    at Manager.module.exports.io.stopServer (/home/streamuser/nodejs/data/io.js:22:10)
    at process.<anonymous> (/home/streamuser/nodejs/data/app.js:146:7)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:345:11)
```

Comment: Do this: app.listen(25544, function(){console.log("server running")}); and check if console outputs 'server running' or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any 1 need, i public solution:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var https = require("https"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    app = https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(BASE_DIR + '/private.pem').toString(),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(BASE_DIR + '/public.pem').toString()
    }),
    io = require("socket.io").listen(app);

    io.listeningClients = false;

    var oldListeners = app.listeners('request').splice(0);
    app.removeAllListeners('request');

    app.on('request', function (req, res) {
        if (! (io.listeningClients || req.url.indexOf('.js') !== -1)) {
            res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.write('Socket.io stop listening. Try again later.');
            res.end();
            return;
        }

        for (var i = oldListeners.length; i--; ) {
            oldListeners[i].call(app, req, res);
        }
    });

    io.set('log level', 1);
    io.set('reconnect', false);
    io.set('reconnection limit', 20000);
    io.set('max reconnection attempts', Infinity);
    io.set('close timeout', 240);
    io.set('heartbeat timeout', 240);
    io.set('heartbeat interval', 120);


    io.startListeningClients = function() {
        if (io.listeningClients) {
            return;
        }

        io.listeningClients = true;
        app.listen(25544, function() {});
    };

    io.stopListeningClients = function() {
        if (! io.listeningClients) {
            return;
        }

        io.listeningClients = false;
        app.close();

        var clients = io.sockets.clients();
        for (var i in clients) {
            clients[i].disconnect();
        }
    };

    return io;
})();
```